# Strange Ordered List

Tags: css, html-lists

OK i have a strange ordered lists that i need to build i am not sure how to do it.

This is the look i am looking for

[image]

This is the HTML...

```
            <ol class="container">
              <li>
                <span>Order: <strong><a href="#">59179</a></strong></span>
                <div>Order Date: <strong>04/29/2013</strong></div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                Status: <strong>In Process</strong>
              </li>
            </ol>
```

The CSS

```
 ol.container li span{float:left;}
 ol.container li div{float:left;padding-left:20px}
```

Everything looks the way that i want it except the 1. is floating to the right for some reason. What am i missing...

[image]

Comment: could you share your entire css or url?

Comment: Try without all the `float:left` in your CSS

Comment: Without the floats they just get lined up vertically.

I have rewritten this CSS a few times and that is all i have to make it look like the bottom screen shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't want to use `float: left` with the span and divs inside the ordered list. You might have more luck using `display: inline-block` on the non-`clear` div. For example:

```
ol.container li span{ }
ol.container li div { display: inline-block;}
ol.container li div.clear { display: block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/CgQgp/

Comment: No worries, I find it's often the way with CSS! Note that IE6 and IE7 don't support `inline-block` on divs. If my answer helped, I'd be very grateful if you could mark it as accepted. Many thanks if you could, best of luck in the future :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay on accepting the answer. Kind of forgot about the post. If you could up vote my question that would b great i was banned from asking questions for some reason i have no idea why.

Comment: Thanks mate, I've voted up your question as it's perfectly clear and well-presented. I can't see why you were banned either. Hope this helps :)